# pypy3's pip can't install jupyter

Tags: pip, pypy

When I use pypy3's pip to install jupyter, it doesn't work always.

`pip install jupyter`

The pypy version I use is `pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32`.

When installing the jupyter, it always throws the AttributeError, like this:

```
Collecting nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/fd/4f/5cbd9bdb30bfaad620f028711bf232b9cec8fdff1dcf68d9259254fcddeb/nbclient-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\myapps\pypy37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 224, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "d:\myapps\pypy37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "d:\myapps\pypy37\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 321, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "d:\myapps\pypy37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
  File "d:\myapps\pypy37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 445, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "d:\myapps\pypy37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 344, in resolve
    success = self._backtrack()
  File "d:\myapps\pypy37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 287, in _backtrack
    criterion = self.state.criteria[name].excluded_of([candidate])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'excluded_of'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get complete details here. It seems your commandline is not correct. Please follow any of the desired from link below. [Jupyter notebook installation](https://jupyter.org/install)